# How to ask the array to return to its first index?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want the index to return to the first one as soon as its done processing all the items. This code doesn't seem to work. can somebody lend me a hand on how to fix this? why is this happening?

One hunch i have is since `buttonArray.length` is not equaling to `arrayPosition` it may be causing the issue. But I tried manually putting 3 and did `(buttonArray.length-1)`. It still didn't work.

```
buttonArray.push (square,triangle,circle,hexagon);

    function clickon(clickTarget:MouseEvent){
        if (clickTarget.target == buttonArray[arrayPosition]){
        trace ("correct");
        trace (buttonArray.length);
        trace (arrayPosition);

        if (buttonArray[arrayPosition]== buttonArray.length)
        {
            arrayPosition = 0;
            trace ("this is working");
        }
        else
        {
            arrayPosition++;
        }
        // inside if loop end
        }
        else
        {
            trace ("not correct");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
if (buttonArray[arrayPosition]== buttonArray.length)
{
          arrayPosition = 0;
          trace ("this is working");
}
```

To:

```
if (arrayPosition == (buttonArray.length-1))
{
          arrayPosition = 0;
          trace ("this is working");
}
```

Comment: Almost there, the correct check will be against the length itself.

Comment: @vesper No I think Snukus answer is correct, as if `arrayPosition` is the last index possible for the array (i.e. `buttonArray.length - 1`), we want to set it to 0 for the next event. If not, then we just increment `arrayPosition` by one.

Comment: I alread mentioned in the question I already tried that it wasn't working heeh.. but thx.

Comment: You need to compare arrayPosition...not buttonArray[arrayPosition].

Comment: @tailedmouse Can you update your question with the new code you tested?

Answer (score 0):

One way to make "arrayPosition" loop around from 0 to buttonArray.length can be to go:

```
arrayPosition++
arrayPosition = arrayPosition % buttonArray.length;
```

Example in a loop:

```
var buttonArray:Array = new Array(14); // array is 14 elements long

var arrayPosition:int = 0;

for(var counter:int = 0; counter < 100; counter++){
    arrayPosition++
    arrayPosition = arrayPosition % buttonArray.length;
    trace(arrayPosition); // goes from 0 to 13, then back to 0 and repeats
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in checking the position, you are checking the element against the array's length, but you should check the position itself.

```
 if (arrayPosition == buttonArray.length)
```